# Android RatingBar show black overlay on some devices

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, ratingbar

I have this ratingbar which is inside the applications and it is always displaying correctly.
But recently I realise that it is not working correctly on some devices (which include Nexus 5 with Lollipop version). **The rating bar are covered by a black overlay as shown on the image below (only on some devices).** When listview (with rating stars) is scrolled, the rating bar will be shown (and then black overlay shows again). it only affect the yellow stars but not the white ones.

I am not sure if anyone had ever met this problem before? I am thinking if it is the recent android update on Nexus 5 that causes this as the rating bar works well on other devices.

[image: Black overlay on rating star]

Comment: provide your code of xml

Comment: Do you maybe tint the rating stars in some way? Are you using the support library? Which version?

Comment: I realise that it might be corrupted file when I was downloading information from the server... it seem like after removing the data and redownload it again it is workings... It could also be because we had change our download link which causes caches data and images. But I am not very certain if that is the main cause as at the point of time no one seem to have that problem.

Comment: I'm sure the problem is rendering-related. Maybe it has something to do with scrolling cache, because when list is scrolled, stars are getting back to normal in my case.

Comment: @KeyhanAsghari I face the same problem the last time where when it scroll back, it return back to normal. And it is only on certain phone (which is Nexus 5 for my case when i test it, other phone like sony z1 and samsung note 3 doesn't have that problem). Maybe you could check your listview adapter (cos when I first take over the project, the previous developer was using `addview` so i had switch to `listview`)? But for my case, the bug was kind of solve by itself after i remove the data and re-download again. (I am just listing out the possibility)

Answer (score 3):

Accoring to me,

**This may be using v21 of the support libraries or possibly unstable OS update** as .xml file and code is not available.

These are the issue reported on google for rating bar please check link below,

[RatingBar rendering broken on devices](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2708)

> The development team has fixed the issue that you have reported and it
>   will be available in a future build.

[RatingBar w/ Custom Stars Drawable is rendered as 1 stretched star on pre-Lollipop phones](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=162419)

> when using v21 of the support libraries, the RatingBar w/ custom stars
>   renders as expected. With v22, instead of 5 stars, you just get one,
>   but stretched to match the width that 5 stars should take
>
> First of all, do not use RatingBar#setProgressDrawable because no
>   matter what platform, it is going to work like #setBackground()
>   (single stretched image for whole background). Secondly, setting
>   android:ratingBarStyle on theme level does not work. I ended up
>   creating custom style, with "android:progressDrawable" and applying it
>   for every view I needed.

[RatingBar does not render in InfoWindow](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=99502)

> setting the style to android:attr/ratingBarStyle does not work, and
>   ratingBarStyleSmall does work